# T/F: If $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{x}{z}$ where $y,z \neq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

T/F: If $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{x}{z}$ where $y,z \neq 0$ then $y=z$

I think this is true but my teacher is known for giving trick questions.

If x=2 then for the left side and right side to be equal, the denominators must be equal.

Any counterexamples or explanations?

Comment: what if $x=0$?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x=0$ we can have easily that $y\neq z$. For example $$\frac{0}{1} = \frac{0}{2}= \frac{0}{3}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

It's tempting to say true since you can write
$$
\frac{x}{y}=\frac{x}{z}
$$
$$
xz = xy
$$
$$
\frac{x}{x}z=y
$$
$$
z=y
$$
BUT on the step where we have $\frac{x}{x}$, this additionally requires that $x \ne 0$.